# PHP Magic methods __get

Tags: php, get, overloading

I'm a bit confused when the magic method __get is called.
Here is a small example

```
class Test {


    public function __get($name) {
        echo $name;
    }

}

$a = new Test;

echo 'a '.$a->b.' c';
```

It output "ba c", though I expected to get "a b c"

Comment: obviously cause `echo $name;` executed before `echo 'a '.$a->b.' c';` try to change your `echo $name;` with `return $name;`

Comment: @BagusTesa You ought to post that as an answer.

Comment: ok @MichaelBerkowski, thank you

Comment: because __get will automatically display the `b` instead of returning it.

Answer (score 1):

well, its because you're calling another `echo` before the calee got called.

```
class Test {


    public function __get($name) {
        return $name;
    }

}

$a = new Test;

echo 'a '.$a->b.' c';
```

Remember, the order of execution. A statement is executed once all function calls inside that function executed. In your code, the `echo 'a '.$a->b.' c';` only get executed after `$a->b` executed where in original code the `$a->b` is **echo**-ing the name of property being asked instead *returning* it to its calee.

Comment: I didn't know about the order of execution. That was my problem. Thanks.